# FancyTree how to link just a portion of the node

Tags: javascript, nodes, fancytree

I've just come across this: I've got a list of nodes showing data in a table:

Column A, Column B, Column C

I set an action when you click the node, checking the type of the node:

```js
activate: function(event, data) {
  if (data.node.isFolder()) {
    return false;
  }
  if (data.node.data.datatype) {
    //doSomething;
  } else if (data.node.data.datatype2) {
    //doSomething;
  } else {
    //doSomething; 
  }
  return false;
}
```

Is there any easy way to, for example, do something (es. go to a link or .do) in column A but another link in column B on the same node?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to inspect the target of the `data.originalEvent`, for example

```
activate: function(event, data) {
  if ( $(data.originalEvent.target).hasClass("...") {
    return false;
  }
```